# Seeing array elements in mongoose js

Tags: javascript, mongoose

so I have this schema for a thread (it's pretty much a chat room:)

```
var threadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    messages: [{
        message:String,
        type:String
    }],
    point_id:String
});
```

I compile into a model as shown:

```
var Thread = mongoose.model('Thread',threadSchema);
```

My problem is that when I access the message element in the thread object like this:

```
console.log(thread_instance.messages);
```

It prints out '[object Object]'. It does this even if I parse it in the browser; it's literally returning that string '[object Object]'.

I believe it has something to do with how I'm pushing to the array:

```
this_thread.messages.push({message:data.message,type:data.type});
```

What is wrong with how I'm writing/reading? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: WHat does the data look like when you query it in mongo directly?

Comment: When I run db.threads.find() I get: { "__v" : 4, "_id" : ObjectId("520dc4921ea8dc0000000002"), "messages" : [  "[object Object]",  "[object Object]",  "[object Object]",  "[object Object]" ], "point_id" : "520dc4921ea8dc0000000001" } Each element in the array just shows up as an object.

Comment: What does the data object look like?

Comment: That's the problem. It's literally the string "[object Object]". I just had to hack it by storing the object as a string and making it an array of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem here is that your array contains a an object where one of the keys is "type".  `type` is used by mongoose to tell it what type a thing in a schema is like this:

```
var ExhibitSchema = new Schema({
    title  : { type: String, trim: true }
    , description : { type: String, trim: true }
    , discussion  :   {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Discussion"} 
    , views: {type: Number, default: 0}
```

So in your case, you are telling mongoose that you have a `messages` array of type string. it probably just ignores the `message:String` part. When you add stuff into that array it calls `toString()` on it to store it. This is why you are seeing the `["[object Object]", "[object Object]"` in the db.

Id fix it by changing your schema to look like this:

```
var threadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    messages: [{
        message:{ type: String},
        type:{ type: String}
    }],
    point_id:String
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`messages` is actually an array of object, So you can specify an index to the messages array like this

```
console.log(thread_instance.messages[0]);
```

if the `messages` array contain more than one element you want a regular for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i<thread_instance.messages.length; i++) {
  // use i as an array index
  console.log(thread_instance.messages[i]);
}
```

So combine all together the code would look like this

```
Thread.find(function (err, thread_instance) {

    for (var i = 0; i<thread_instance.messages.length; i++) {
      // use i as an array index
      console.log(thread_instance.messages[i]);
    }  

})
```

Comment: as he pointed out in the comment, `[object Object]` is actually stored in the db